An effect of explaining something to others
I often noticed that when I explain something to someone, the things that I said are not an "insight" for that person only, but also for myself. This is when I may say something like "Wow! I never realized it myself before I explained it to you!"
How does this effect is called?

In the world of software development, this is called rubber ducking -- when you are trying to solve a mysterious bug, and you explain it in detail to someone else, often you will realize the answer yourself simply from the process of explaining the bug to the other person.  In fact the other person might as well not have been there at all, and a rubber duck could have taken their place.

@JohnGordon Hello, John. I know about rubber ducking, but it seems this effect is familiar to almost any person (I heard about it from my parents, my friends, etc.), and so it seems it is a very common thing, and so I suppose it has a name outside of software development world.
